# Align div elements to the right

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align the elements inside a Facebook Like / Share `div` to the right but none of the methods I'm finding works. Here's a screenshot:

[image: This is not how I want it.]

What I'd like is for everything to be aligned to the right. Basically I tried everything but nothing works. This is the `div` code:

```
<div style='background-color: #b0c4de;'
   class="fb-like"
   data-share="true"
   data-width="15"
   data-show-faces="true">
</div>
```

What am I missing?

EDIT: This is hardly a solution but it's a hack I can live with for now. It's pushing the entire div - not the elements which is what I really need - to a place that sort of aligns correctly in the context of the page.

```
<div style='position:relative; right:-50px;'...
```

Comment: not sure if I'm right, but usually the facebook stuff is in an iframe... you can't usually edit styles inside of an iframe.

Comment: That appears to be his own div with several facebook buttons. `<div style='text-align: right;'`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="float: right;">Right Div</div>
```

Comment: He wants to align the elements within the `div`, not the `div` itself. Are the children elements going to inherit `float: right`? Doubt that.

Comment: It doesn't work. Maybe the 'class="fb-like"' is overriding the float?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="text-align: right;">Share</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide some explanation for the OP about what this code is doing?

Comment: he wants to align the text Like & share to the right.

Comment: It doesn't work. Maybe the 'class="fb-like"' is overriding it?

Comment: use `text-align: right !important;` important is used to increase the priority.

Answer (score 0):

Use the HTML  align Attribute:

> Syntax
>   `<div align="left|right|center|justify">`
>
> [enter link description here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_div_align.asp)Attribute Values
>
> - Value   Description
>
>   - left=align content left
>   - right-align content right
>   - center=-align content to Center
>   - justify=Stretches the lines so that each line has equal width (like in newspapers and magazines)